# dial tcp :0: connect: connection refused

Tags: mysql, linux, go, go-gorm

When I use gorm to connect to mysql, the result shows that the  connection refused

This is application.yaml

```
applications: 
 url: 127.0.0.1
 userName: dog
 passWord: 123456
 dbName: douyin
 port: 3306
```

```
// InitMySql Initialize connection database
func InitMySql() (err error) {
    var c conf
    // Get yaml configuration parameters
    conf := c.getConf()
    // Splice the yaml configuration parameters into the url to connect to the database
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local",
        conf.UserName,
        conf.PassWord,
        conf.Url,
        conf.Port,
        conf.DbName,
    )
    // Connect to database
    SqlSession, err = gorm.Open(DRIVER, dsn)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // Verify whether the database connection is successful. If successful, there is no exception
    return SqlSession.DB().Ping()
}
```

```
root@ezra-virtual-machine:/home/ezra# netstat -an | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I can connect to the database using the command line

Comment: maybe something wrong with your getConf method. Print the string after Sprintf

Comment: Connection refused means you cannot even connect to mysql. Usually this is aresult of incorrect host name, port, or something blocking the connection. We cannot tell you by looking at your code which of the above causes the problem.

Comment: The error message would indicate that both url and port have their zero values (empty string and zero, respectively).